# MariaDb: how to find mathematical calculation based on derived results in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a large SQL like so:

(MariaDb V5.5.65)

```
SELECT ....,
...,
SUM(BJ.intake) as intakeX,
(SELECT SUM(ibj.intake) FROM ibj WHERE ibj.p2p3 = 'P3' AND ne.see_id = ibj.ee_id ) as p3count,
...,
...
FROM NewEstablished ne  
INNER JOIN BlindJob BJ ON ...
WHERE ...
```

This works perfectly.

I need to however add a derived column, which is a ratio of `p3count` / `intakeX` * 100 . Both derived values are decimal, but I can't seem to find how to reference them in the select:

```
SELECT ....,
...,
SUM(BJ.intake) as intakeX,
(SELECT SUM(ibj.intake) FROM ibj WHERE ibj.p2p3 = 'P3' AND ne.see_id = ibj.ee_id ) as p3count,
(p3count / intakeX * 100) as ratio, 
...,
...
FROM NewEstablished ne  
INNER JOIN BlindJob BJ ON ...
WHERE ...
```

This returns an error that `p3count` / `intakeX` are unknown columns.

I have seen elsewhere that these *derived* select columns are set as being part of the FROM table (in this case `ne`) but that also does not seem to work.

How can I reference these SELECT values to do a further calculation on them as a new output column?

Example output:

> ```
> intakeX = 25
> p3count = 2
> ratio = 8
> ```

Comment: What clarity is missing from this question?

Comment: To accomplish this in a single SELECT,  we would have to *repeat* the expressions. To be able to reference the assigned aliases, we need a second SELECT, either a CTE or an inline view (wrap the SELECT in a set of parens, and put it in the FROM clause of an outer query i.e. make it into an inline view, what mysql calls a derived table), then the outer query has the column aliases available to reference. What is missing from MySQL is an extension like the Teradata-style `NAMED` keyword for use in place of `AS`, Teradata allows NAMED aliases to be referenced elsewhere in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your query as subquery and calculate the new column:

```
select t.*,
  (t.p3count / t.intakeX * 100) as ratio
from (
  <your query>
) t
```

or for MySql 8.0+ you can use a `CTE`:

```
with CTE as (
  <your query>
)
select *,
  (p3count / intakeX * 100) as ratio
from cte
```

The other option is to repeat the same expressions:

```
SELECT ....,
...,
SUM(BJ.intake) as intakeX,
(SELECT SUM(ibj.intake) FROM ibj WHERE ibj.p2p3 = 'P3' AND ne.see_id = ibj.ee_id ) as p3count,
(
  (SELECT SUM(ibj.intake) FROM ibj WHERE ibj.p2p3 = 'P3' AND ne.see_id = ibj.ee_id ) / 
  SUM(BJ.intake) * 
  100
) as ratio, 
...,
...
FROM NewEstablished ne  
INNER JOIN BlindJob BJ ON ...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I am using MariaDb.  I was under an impression that there was a syntax to do this without needing to wrap everything within a deeper Select clause?

Comment: The other option is to repeat the same expressions. I will edit.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I thought I was missing something more obvious.